# Placing movieClip object in AS3 below(in depth - think of z-index) timeline layer in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Flash ad. I use AS3 generated objects as well as movieclips placed manually in the timeline. Although the AS3 layer is below my manually placed timeline layers, the AS3 placed movieclips are visible "above/on top of/have higher z-index than" my timeline layers.

I am aware of handling the display order of AS3 generated objects via [display list model](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html), like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500017/stage-addchild-and-layering).

However I cannot find information in which way timeline layers(Flash IDE layers) are correlated to AS3 generated "display object containers".
Edit: Obviously IDE layers are out of scope of the display list model, but I have no source for that.

Basically I only want to make sure that my transparent clickTag-button-layer is above all content in my ad. Currently the AS3 placed movieClips are above it.

Comment: Provide the code you are using add and manipulate the depth of these MovieClips. Without that we can only speculate as to what could be your issue.  With that said, you want consider manually placing an empty MovieClip in your timeline, below the other objects, and adding your AS3 generated objects into it.

Comment: You may also want to loop over the children on your Stage and see what order they are in. `stage.getChildIndex()`  You will be surprised by the difference by index of timeline objects verse the ones placed by AS code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that empty MovieClip approach. I have not added any code, as currently I am not changing the "ordering" of the AS3 generated objects at all. I tried the container approach from the display list model, but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: @C.Parcell Thank you, this solved my problem. I placed an empty MovieClip where I place the AS3 generated content. Also just now I found the info, that Flash IDE layers are not part of the AS3 display list model, so they cannot be managed from AS3.

Comment: It's a question of timing. I do assume that you use multiple frames and in that case the content is always generated again and again as you move through the frames meaning it gets on top of everything. It's a question of timing because all content generated by code should be added on top AFTER the timeline content appears. If it appears under it's because that code run before that timeline content gets added.

Comment: @BotMaster As I am mixing AS3 generated and "manually" placed and motion tweened MovieClips in Flash IDE my timeline has 360 frames. I already thought that as the dynamic MovieClips are added "last", they get on the top, as the addChild() function also determines the ordering - last added is on top.

Comment: It's a nightmare scenario but you can still get away with it by placing a layer on top of everything then in that layer put an empty moviecliip then add all your coded content in it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question, but you can use `setChildIndex` to set elements depths, take a look here for more information : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex().

Comment: Thanks, but in my context with Flash IDE layers and AS3 generated content this did not help. I tried this method and I set the index to 0 and even negative values, still the AS3 generated content was placed above the content in my layers.

Comment: You should do that after drawing all elements like this : `function set_depths(){ 
 var n = this.numChildren; 
 n--; setChildIndex(clp_01, n);
 n--; setChildIndex(clp_02, n);
 n--; setChildIndex(clp_03, n);
}`